# Make div cover the entire visible part of the viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's an example to give you an idea of what I want to achieve: [Startup Framework](http://designmodo.com/startup/)

I want to make a div cover the entire current visible part of the viewport like the div with the video on it on the link shows.

I'm trying to accomplish something similar but currently I just can't really pull it off. This is what I have so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/BHe3k/)

Where I use `100%` height for the first div.

```
body{height: 100%; width: 100%;}
.special-jumbotron{height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url(http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/17/7/cool-background-wallpaper-keyboard-abstract-other-177639.jpg) center center fixed; background-size: cover; color: #ddd; text-shadow: 3px 4px #333;}
```

I'm brainstorming how to achieve this effect, but nothing has worked so far and I'm out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The picked solution is ok and viewport units although not supported on older browsers can be implemented using a shim: http://html5polyfill.com/.  A more efficient way to accomplish the effect you are seeking is to set the `height` of `100%` on both the `body` and `html`: http://jsfiddle.net/BHe3k/6/.  Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `height:100vh`, Its new CSS units relative to viewport height (vh) and viewport width (vw). Supported by modern browsers and IE >= 9.

Complete css:

```
.special-jumbotron {
height:100vh;
min-height:100%;
max-height:100%;
background:url(http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/17/7/cool-background-wallpaper-keyboard-abstract-other-177639.jpg) center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
color:#ddd;
text-shadow:3px 4px #333;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MtAzc/2/)

If you want to test its responsive or not. check in full screen. [<kbd>Full screen Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/MtAzc/2/embedded/result/)

This can also achive using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.special-jumbotron').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});//on load
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
        $('.special-jumbotron').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
```

[<kbd>Jquery Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/UM32B/2/)

Comment: This solves part of the issue. However it exceeds the viewport size and I need it to be responsive just like the link I provided. Not a single pixel more not a single pixel less than the current visible viewport height and width. Can I manage to achieve this?

Comment: Just figured it works. One more question. If I have a navbar from bootstrap there, should the measure still be 100vw?

Comment: @hsoto jqeury is is perfect solution then. and your example link also using jquery for setting height. Because using css you can't control resize of window. if you have `Navbar` then you can give your div height like `windowheight-navheight`

Comment: Use may also want to use this plugin https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill (not mine) as iOS 7 is a bit buggy in using the vh/vw

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by setting `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BHe3k/4/.

Comment: This is not the way to go. I can't imagine position absolute being used on a mobile approach layout.

Comment: Where in the requirements did you post about mobile layout?

Answer (score 0):

min-height:100vh;
min-width:100vw;

This also solves the problem for viewports that are taller than they are wide.